# Permission Issues with /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt

Tags: 14.04, permissions, ssl

When trying to `curl` or `git clone` something over HTTPS as a regular user, it fails with the error:

```
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/mikemackintosh/xxx/': Problem with the SSL CA cert (path? access rights?)
```

*Note*: If i run the commands as root, it works fine, but root should not be the only user able to communicate over ssl.

So I think to myself, ok, what's curl doing behind the scenes:

```
$ GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1 git clone https://github.com/mikemackintosh/xxx
Cloning into 'xxx'...
* Couldn't find host github.com in the .netrc file; using defaults
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 192.30.252.130...
* Connected to github.com (192.30.252.130) port 443 (#0)
* error reading ca cert file /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt (Error while reading file.)
* Closing connection 0
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/mikemackintosh/xxx/': Problem with the SSL CA cert (path? access rights?)
```

As a result, we are able to confirm the `ca-certificate` file is: `/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt` which matches `curl-config -ca` output.

The next step is to try and read the file. As just a plain-old, non-root user:

```
$ cat /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
cat: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt: Permission denied
```

Now that seems strange.

```
$ sudo ls -la /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 273790 Jun 15 22:35 /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt

$ sudo lsattr /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
-------------e-- /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
```

So looking at the permissions, it is world-readable. There should be no problem accessing it. No crazy attributes preventing access.

doing an `ls -la /etc/ssl/certs/` returns:

```
...
l????????? ? ? ? ?            ? Verisign_Class_4_Public_Primary_Certification_Authority_-_G3.pem
l????????? ? ? ? ?            ? VeriSign_Universal_Root_Certification_Authority.pem
l????????? ? ? ? ?            ? Visa_eCommerce_Root.pem
l????????? ? ? ? ?            ? WellsSecure_Public_Root_Certificate_Authority.pem
l????????? ? ? ? ?            ? WoSign_China.pem
l????????? ? ? ? ?            ? WoSign.pem
...
```

If I run a `sudo cat /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.pem`, it spits out the contents as expected.

Oh, this is for sure a permissions issue.

Doing some googling, i've found that there is an `ssl-cert` group, but this group does not have rights to the `/etc/ssl/certs` directory.

Ruled out apparmor, ruled out disk corruption, there is no improvement if I run `update-ca-certificates (w/wo -f)`, etc.

Has anyone seen this behavior?

I have never seen anything like this before, but I have duplicated it on two separate machines. As a note, I do come from a CentOS/RHEL background, so this could be a normal behavior of Ubuntu, but i'd love to find out a real solution.

Comment: What happens if you do `dpkg-reconfigure ca-certificates` and try again? `sudo apt-get install --reinstall ca-certificates`?

Comment: No changes when running those two..  still get permission denied.

Comment: It ended up being a very poorly Chef cookbook that was included as a dependency that was changing the certificate directories' permissions.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Run `namei -mo /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt`.  Match its output to the following:

```
f: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
 drwxr-xr-x root root /
 drwxr-xr-x root root etc
 drwxr-xr-x root root ssl
 drwxr-xr-x root root certs
 -rw-r--r-- root root ca-certificates.crt
```

You can use `chmod` and `chown` to get everything back to the correct settings:

- `sudo chown root /  && chown root /etc/ && chown root /etc/ssl/ && chown root /etc/ssl/certs/ && chown root /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt`
- `sudo chmod 755 /`
- `sudo chmod 755 /etc/`
- `sudo chmod 755 /etc/ssl/`
- `sudo chmod 755 /etc/ssl/certs`
- `sudo chmod 644 /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt`

Comment: FYI, to save you the trouble of looking it up: `755` corresponds to `rwxr-xr-x`, and `644` corresponds to `rw-r--r--`

Answer (score 7):

I encountered the same issue today. Here is what I did:

> GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1 git clone https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh.git

This clones repository in curl verbose mode (curl is causing issue right now)

Here is what I got

```
Cloning into 'oh-my-zsh'...
* Couldn't find host github.com in the .netrc file; using defaults
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 192.30.252.131...
* Connected to github.com (192.30.252.131) port 443 (#0)
* error reading ca cert file /bin/curl-ca-bundle.crt (Error while reading file.)
* Closing connection 0
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh.git/': Problem with the SSL CA cert (path? access rights?)
```

Note the line:

> - error reading ca cert file /bin/curl-ca-bundle.crt (Error while reading file.)

I had a configuration issue in `~/.gitconfig` `[HTTP]->sslCAinfo`  section. You might not have the same issue, but it will give you enough information to debug on your own.

Comment: This was very useful! Solved my issue. My sslCAinfo was mistaken as well.

Answer (score 3):

In unix, the whole path is checked, so in my opinion, you should check if the folders in the path have permissions, I think, they should have at least rw-, don't panic, w doesn't mean write if talking about folders...
Because if you have /a/b/c/certificate.pem and you can't get past "b", you can't get past b :D

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thanks, i forgot to add that to the OP, but 
```
~$ ls -la /etc/ | grep ssl
drwxr-xr-x   4 root root    4096 Jun 13 23:02 ssl

~$ ls -la /etc/ssl/ | grep cert
drw-r--r--   2 root root 20480 Jun 16 00:58 certs```

Comment: well it seems strange to me, maybe you could try just setting the curl-config -ca path to somewhere else and copy there the certs it needs. I know this is not the solution you're looking for, but it is a solution at least...

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you've CA certificates to allow SSL-based applications to check for the authenticity of SSL connections. They can be installed by:

```
sudo apt-get install ca-certificates openssl
```

This can be missing especially in Docker or CI containers.

If you have it, consider reinstalling it.

You can also try running: `sudo update-ca-certificates`.

Related:

- [cURL not working (Error #77) for SSL connections](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55859036/55075)
- [curl: (77) pbm with the SSL CA cert (path? access rights?)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/269614/21471)